# how do i get all images in a grid the same height using css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image: see how the one image is the wring height]

I am trying to get all images are the same height but I don't know what is wrong here. all images are the same dimensions.

here is the CSS

```
.shop-now-grid {
   display: grid; 
   position: relative;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   max-height: 500px;
   max-width: 1700px;
   height: 100%;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
   margin: auto;
   grid-gap: 5%;

}
  
#shop-grid-0 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/about_values_f13f2034-9acd-41df-a7a3-2cae150c79ac_650x.jpg?v=1526915323&auto=format&q=50&); 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   background-size: auto;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;


   
   
}

#shop-grid-0 .shop-now-0 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-0 .title-0 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;;
    top: 50%;;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-1 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/DSC07022_650x.jpg?v=1526856532&auto=format&q=50&);
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   background-size: auto;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;
   
}

#shop-grid-1 .shop-now-1 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-1 .title-1 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-2 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/home_brew_wares_650x.jpg?v=1526915416&auto=format&q=50&); 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 3;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 4;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
   position: relative;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;
   
   
}

#shop-grid-2 .shop-now-2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-2 .title-2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

    .shop-now-grid {
   display: grid; 
   position: relative;
   grid-template-rows: 1fr;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   max-height: 500px;
   max-width: 1700px;
   height: 100%;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
   margin: auto;

}
  
#shop-grid-0 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/about_values_f13f2034-9acd-41df-a7a3-2cae150c79ac_650x.jpg?v=1526915323&auto=format&q=50&); 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   background-size: auto;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;

   
   
}

#shop-grid-0 .shop-now-0 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-0 .title-0 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;;
    top: 50%;;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-1 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/DSC07022_650x.jpg?v=1526856532&auto=format&q=50&);
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   position: relative;
   background-size: auto;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;
   
}

#shop-grid-1 .shop-now-1 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-1 .title-1 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-2 {

   background-image: url(https://swallowtailtea.imgix.net/s/files/1/2960/1850/files/home_brew_wares_650x.jpg?v=1526915416&auto=format&q=50&); 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 3;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 4;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
   position: relative;
   background-size: contain;
   max-width:auto;
   max-height:auto;
   
   
}

#shop-grid-2 .shop-now-2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

#shop-grid-2 .title-2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: GT Pressura Mono,Roboto Mono,monospace;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}
```

I have tried giving a max height and min-height as well as just hard coding the numbers but it does not seem to work. And the thing I find interesting is that all the text is at the same height/position.

HTML

```
<div class="shop-now-grid">
            <div id="shop-grid-0"><h1 class="shop-now-0">shop now</h1><h1 class="title-0">teas</h1></div>
            <div id="shop-grid-1"><h1 class="shop-now-1">shop now</h1><h1 class="title-1">mearch</h1></div>
            <div id="shop-grid-2"><h1 class="shop-now-2">shop now</h1><h1 class="title-2">wares</h1></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: @AStombaugh iv showen the CSS and html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on @The Duo's answer, be sure to add image `width` and `height` attributes to avoid [CLS](https://web.dev/cls/).

```css
.row1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <div>
      <img width="640" height="360" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img width="640" height="500" src="https://loremflickr.com/640/500">
    </div>

    <div>
       <img width="700" height="360" src="https://placebear.com/700/360">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `grid-template-columns`

```css
.row1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row1">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360">
    </div>

    <div>
       <img src="https://placebear.com/640/360">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: iv expanded my code to show the CSS and HTML.  Would the way I'm doing it work or am I missing something. Or should I do it like your example?

Comment: You'll have more control over image like this . I'll look into your method .